# Input and store to Array

Tags: android

I'm new to android programming and not really good at java programming.
Simple question here:How to store value typed in EditText to array once button
is pressed, the way that I will able to compare each index to a constant value of
another variable.

Comment: Evidently you are new to asking questions, too. Search SO for edittext and you will find several likely answers.

Comment: Use `ArrayList` as an array to store values, use `editText.getText().toString()` to get value of `EditText`! You should search google before asking any question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//your array
String[n] array;

//your button
Button b;

///your edittext
EditText e;

if(b.isPressed())
array[x]=edit.getText().toString();
```

OR using ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> n= new ArrayList<String>();

//your button
Button b;

///your edittext
EditText e;


if(b.isPressed())
n.add(edit.getText().toString());
```

Comment: These are worked fine on me, may help someone.

ArrayList<String> editTextList = new ArrayList<String>();
editTextList.add(textView4.getText().toString());
editText3.setText(editTextList.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quite easy. 
xml layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <EditText
         android:id="@+id/txtField"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in your activity you type the following:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtField);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
          String s = text.getText().toString();
              // then you do whatever you like with it
    }
});
```